# AJAX GET requests in Java

Tags: java, ajax, url, ajax-request

I'm trying to make a GET AJAX request on some site using java.

My code is the following:

```
    String cookie = getRandomString(16); //Getting a random 32-symbol string

    String url = "https://e-kassa.org/core/ajax/stations_search.php?"
            + "q=%D0%BE&limit=10&timestamp=1352028872503";
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

    conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "PHPSESSID=" + cookie);
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

    int buffer;
    while((buffer = is.read()) != -1)
        System.out.print(buffer);

    is.close();
    conn.disconnect();
```

But the problem is that there's nothing to download from the InputStream is. But if I use my browser to do the same thing, I'll get a response, composed of text lines of the following format:

> CITY_NAME|SOME_DIGITS

So, can anybody tell me, how can I make such a request in an appropriate manner?

UPD: without cookies I have the same behaviour (in the browser everything's fine, but not in Java).

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try with:

```
BufferedReader rd = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://e-kassa.org/core/ajax/stations_search.php?"
            + "q=%D0%BE&limit=10&timestamp=1352028872503");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            String cookie = (new RandomString(32)).nextString();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "PHPSESSID=" + cookie);
            // Get the response
            rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (rd != null) {
                try {
                    rd.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
```

This is peace of code that works properly in my projects. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following thing.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        String url = "https://e-kassa.org/core/ajax/stations_search.php?"
            + "q=%D0%BE&limit=10&timestamp=1352028872503";
        URL url = new URL(url);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "PHPSESSID=" + cookie);
        connection.connect();
        connection.getInputStream();
        int buffer;
        while((buffer = is.read()) != -1)
           System.out.print(buffer);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(null != connection) { connection.disconnect(); }
    }
```

Comment: Still the same result. Actually, there's no exception thrown here.